# Sql server table with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Need some input
I need to create table with colprimkey1,col2,colyear,day1,day2,day3,...day366  like this(to have less records otherwise will be ending with billion records) in azure/synapse
will it better for DML mainly updates and give better performance(This will be unpivoted later) rather then the same table having like

colprimkey1,col2,colyear,dayofyear,daydata then
1,xx,2020,'day1',88
1,xx,2021,'day4',28?

I am trying
colprimkey1,col2,colyear,day1,day2,day3,...day366
1,xx,2020,88,10,34,28,...41

Any other suggestions for efficiency,storage, performance etc
Thanks in advance

I tried with small data and but not in big scale only think considering is it will reduce the number of records in table but column wise more data will be there.

if anyone worked in similar situation and got better solution let me know

Comment: billions of records isn't a problem if your table is indexed correctly. Hundreds of column is a mess and a design smell

Comment: Trading rows for columns is generally a bad idea. You end up with the same data in terms of size, just far more uncomfortable queries. The engine certainly isn't going to like you more because you have fewer rows, if the tradeoff is many, many more columns. You also end up with horrific logic issues like "ignore day 366 here because it's not a leap year". What you've got here are dates -- store them as such. Do not proactively split the date into parts either -- you can always make computed columns and index those, should that turn out to be useful (but usually querying ranges suffices).

Comment: Depending on your data, if the day columns would be sparsely filled, you could have another table that was colprimarykey, day, then a field with the data.  When you join to, it would be a fast index seek.

Answer (score 0):

> if anyone worked in similar situation and got better solution let me know

Yea, I've worked with multi-terabyte tables with 10s of billions of rows in each of those tables.

> Any other suggestions for efficiency,storage, performance

Don't trade rows for columns. Architect your tables properly and use the appropriate indexing designed after the types of queries you plan to run.

> will it better for DML mainly updates and give better performance

Nope, in fact it might be worse for performance, especially when trying to search multiple columns or piecing the data back together.

A B-Tree index has an `O(log(n))` search time complexity. If your table had 1 billion rows, in the worst case `log2(1 billion)` = 40. That's only 40 nodes that would need to be seeked through to find any subset of data you're searching for. If your table grew to 1 trillion rows, `log2(1 trillion) = 50`. My graphing calculator could seek through 50 nodes in under a second, any modern computer in a few milliseconds or less.

If you plan to do aggregative type of queries, then a columnstore index may be even more efficient for you from both a compression standpoint and from batch mode operations.

If you split your rows into multiple columns, you lose the efficiency gains of the above, and need to write more complicated queries to search and reshape the data. An unpivot operation on billions of rows will take a very long time.